# SwiftUI share same navigation bar after clicking navigation link

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swift5, navigationview

My app currently has a modal sheet that displays a view inside of a NavigationView. When I click on the NavigationLink I created, it takes me to the destination view in the same modal sheet, but I no longer have access to the navigation bar properties of the previous view (i.e. I can't set the navigation bar title or add navigation items).

I tried making another NavigationView in my second view, but this draws the navigation bar title 1/3 down the screen, and it also prevents me closing out of the entire modal sheet with my @Environment property-wrapped Binding variable. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could fix this?

Not sure if this sounded clear at all, but I will be happy to clarify.

Comment: No idea, until you provide code that does this.